# jQuery: Grab date & time data from web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

As part of an on-going project, I need to seek out and grab date & time data from web pages.

However, while there *appear* to be certain conventions for the date & time format, such as the [Dublin Core Metadata Initiative](http://dublincore.org/about-us/), adoption is poor and adherence is, at best, inconsistent.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: I applaud the effort to ask and answer your own question, with a solution to a problem you seem to have spent a considerable time researching. However, it seems very specific to something you're doing, and it's not even clear what it solves, or what the issue is?

Comment: Grabbing date & time data from web pages.

Answer (score -2):

I am by no means a JavaScript or jQuery expert, but I have the superpower of persistence, and what I've written is working, which is available for forking as a [Gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/OctaneInteractive/30e0967fb93b144810a2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var objDateTimeTags = new Object({
            // The Dublin Core Metadata Initiative (DCMI) ( http://dublincore.org/about-us/ ).
            option1: function () {
                var datetime_published = $("meta[name='DC.Date']").attr("content");
                return validation(datetime_published);
            },
            option2: function () {
                var datetime_published = $("dc\\:date").text();
                return validation(datetime_published);
            },
            /**
              * Sources include:
              * - IFL Science ( http://www.iflscience.com/ );
              * - Popular Mechanics ( http://www.popularmechanics.com/ );
              * - The Guardian ( http://www.theguardian.com/ );
              * - Laughing Squid ( http://laughingsquid.com/ );
              * - Fast Company ( http://www.fastcocreate.com/ ).
            */
            option3: function () {
                var datetime_published = $("meta[property='article:published_time']").attr("content");
                return validation(datetime_published);
            },
            /**
              * Sources include:
              * - New York Times ( http://www.nytimes.com/ ).
            */
            option4: function () {
                var datetime_published = $("meta[name='ptime']").attr("content");
                var datetime_published_formatted = function(datetime) {
                    // Example: 20140911212613, which is equivalent to: 2014-09-11T21:26:13
                    if ( (typeof datetime !== 'undefined') && (datetime.length === 14) ) {
                        // Date.
                        var yyyy = datetime.slice(0, 4);
                        var mm = datetime.slice(4, 6);
                        var dd = datetime.slice(6, 8);
                        // Time.
                        var hours = datetime.slice(8, 10);
                        var minutes = datetime.slice(10, 12);
                        var seconds = datetime.slice(12, 14);
                        // Date & Time.
                        return datetime = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + 'T' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                };
                var datetime_published = datetime_published_formatted(datetime_published);
                return validation(datetime_published);
            },
            /**
              * Sources include:
              * - Science Magazine ( http://news.sciencemag.org/ );
              * - Politico ( http://www.politico.com/ ).
            */
            option5: function () {
                var datetime_published = $("time").attr("datetime");
                return validation(datetime_published);
            },
            /**
              * Sources include:
              * - BBC News ( http://www.bbc.com/news ).
            */
            option6: function () {
                var datetime_published = $('.date').data("seconds") * 1000;
                return validation(datetime_published);
            },
            /**
              * Sources include:
              * - Business Insider ( http://www.businessinsider.com/ ).
            */
            option7: function () {
                var datetime_published = $("span[data-bi-format='date']").attr('rel') * 1000;
                return validation(datetime_published);
            },
            /**
              * Reference: https://www.parsely.com/docs/integration/metadata/ppage.html
              * Sources include:
              * - Ars Technica ( http://arstechnica.com/ );
              * - The Next Web ( http://thenextweb.com/ );
              * - Live Science ( http://www.livescience.com/ );
              * - The Atlantic ( http://www.theatlantic.com/ );
              * - The Slate ( http://www.slate.com/ ).
            */
            option8: function () {
                var json = $.parseJSON( ( $("meta[name='parsely-page']").attr("content") ) ? $("meta[name='parsely-page']").attr("content") : false );
                var datetime_published_formatted = function(datetime) {
                    /**
                      * Examples include:
                      * - 2015-12-28T20:10:25Z
                      * - 2015-12-22 at 08:05:00AM EST
                    */
                    if ( typeof datetime !== 'undefined' ) {
                        if ( /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}?Z/.test(datetime) ) {
                            return datetime;
                        } else if ( /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} at \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\w{3} \w{3}/.test(datetime) ) {
                            var arrdt = datetime.split(' at ');
                            // Date.
                            var d = arrdt[0];
                            // Time.
                            var t = arrdt[1].slice(0, 8);
                            // Date & Time.
                            return d + 'T' + t;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                };
                var datetime_published = datetime_published_formatted( (typeof json.pub_date !== 'undefined') ? json.pub_date : '' );
                return validation(datetime_published);
            },
            /**
              * Sources include:
              * - USA Today ( http://www.usatoday.com/ ).
            */
            option9: function() {
                var datetime_published = $("meta[itemprop='datePublished']").attr("content");
                return validation(datetime_published);
            },
            /**
              * Sources include:
              * - i09 ( http://io9.gizmodo.com/ ).
            */
            option10: function() {
                var json = $.parseJSON( ( $("script[type='application/ld+json']").html() ) ? $("script[type='application/ld+json']").html() : false );
                return validation( (typeof json.datePublished !== 'undefined') ? json.datePublished : '' );
            },
            /**
              * Sources include:
              * - i100 from the Independent ( http://i100.independent.co.uk/ ).
            */
            option11: function() {
                var datetime_published = $("article").data("releasedate");
                return validation(datetime_published);
            },
            /**
              * Sources include:
              * - Daily Kos ( http://www.dailykos.com/ ).
            */
            option12: function() {
                var datetime_published = $("span.timestamp").first().data("epoch-time");
                var datetime_published_formatted = function(datetime) {
                    if ( typeof datetime !== 'undefined' ) {
                        return datetime.toString().slice(0, 10) * 1000;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                };
                return validation(datetime_published_formatted(datetime_published));
            },
            /**
              * Sources include:
              * - Vanity Fair ( http://www.vanityfair.com/ ).
            */
            option13: function() {
                var datetime_published = $("meta[name='pubdate']").attr("content");
                return validation(datetime_published);
            }
        });

    // Helper functions.

    Date.prototype.getUnixTime = function() { return this.getTime() / 1000|0 };

    function validation (datetime) {
        return ( (new Date( datetime )) > 0 ) ? (new Date( datetime ).getUnixTime()) : '';
    }

    // Reference: https://gist.github.com/kmaida/6045266
    function get_timestamp_from_unix_epoch (datetime) {
        // Example: 1449854274, which is equivalent to: 2015-12-11 17:17:54
        if ( (typeof datetime !== 'undefined') && (datetime.length === 10) ) {
            var dt = new Date(datetime * 1000), // Convert the passed timestamp to milliseconds
                        // Date.
                        yyyy = dt.getFullYear(),
                        mm = ('0' + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2), // Months are zero based, so add a leading 0.
                        dd = ('0' + dt.getDate()).slice(-2), // Add leading 0.
                        // Time.
                        hours = dt.getHours(),
                        minutes = ('0' + dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2), // Add leading 0.
                        seconds = ('0' + dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2), // Add leading 0.
                        time;
            // Date & Time.
            return time = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function getDatePublication () {
        var datetime;
        for (var key in objDateTimeTags) {
            datetime = get_timestamp_from_unix_epoch( objDateTimeTags[key]().toString() );
            if (datetime !== false) break;
        }
        // A default value, in the event no date & time value is found.
        return (datetime) ? datetime : '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
    }

    alert ( getDatePublication() );

});
```